# yii2 как изменить базу данных в Query Builder?

Tags: php, yii2

Пример:

`$query = (new \yii\db\Query())->select()->from('table');`

Запрос выполняеться для базы которая db.

Такой вариант `$query = (new \yii\db\Query()) ->select) ->from('table') ->all(\Yii::$app->db2);` не подходит, так как это пойдет в ActiveDataProvider

Как изменить db (базу данных) в Query Builder?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для использования нескольких БД в Yii2 нужно сделать следующее:
Добавляете в config/web.php

```
'components' => [
    'db1' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1name',
        'username' => 'db1username',
        'password' => 'db1password',
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db2name', 
        'username' => 'db2username',
        'password' => 'db2password',
    ],
],
```

Обращаетесь так:

```
//k db1
Yii::$app->db1->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')->from('tbl_name'))->queryAll();

//к db2
Yii::$app->db2->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')->from('tbl_name'))->queryAll();
```

Если используете ActiveRecord модель, то:

```
//db1
public function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->db1;
}
```

Удачного кодинга...